# getEntity with GenericType

Tags: java, jersey, generic-list, generic-type-argument

Trying to get an Entity from a REST service. My code is like this:

I want to send in an object like this: `new GenericType<List<MyObject>>() {}`

to a methode like this:

```
public static Object callRestWithUrl(String url, Class<?> responseObject)
            throws MetaServiceException {

        ClientResponse response = RESTConnectionUtils.callMetaService(url);

            result = response.getEntity(responseObject);

        .....
```

But it gets evaluated to List during runtime and not GenericType and an exception is thrown.

Answer (score 4):

How do you invoke your callRestWithUrl method?

It could be that it would work better if your method had the signature:

```
public static Object callRestWithUrl(String url, GenericType<List<?>> responseObject)
```

And that you then invoked it as this:

```
List<...> list = callRestWithUrl(new GenericType<List<MyObject>>() {});
```

Maybe this web page can help:
http://persistentdesigns.com/wp/2009/10/jersey-rest-client/

Answer (score 0):

For some reason it started working as is. No idea why. The input to the method needed to be generic.