# Jersey Client Xml Collection Unmarshalling

Tags: java, xml, rest, jax-rs, jersey-client

I'm writing a rest client using [jersey-client v2.3.1](https://jersey.java.net/) and need to unmarshal an xml response with a root node containing a collection of widget nodes. Like something resembling the following ...

```xml
<widgets>
    <widget />
    ...
    <widget />
</widgets>
```

Currently I have a Widget model ...

```java
public class Widget {
    ...
}
```

However I do not have a wrapper for this model (at least not yet), but I presume I could create one that would allow the response to be unmarshalled. It'd probably look something like this ...

```java
@XmlRootElement(name="widgets")
public class WidgetResponse {
    @XmlElement(name="widget")
    public Widget[] widgets;
}
```

In which case my rest call would likely be ...

```java
ClientBuilder.newClient()
    .target("http://host/api")
    .path("resource")
    .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    .get(WidgetsResponse.class)
```

My question is, can the request be unmarshalled nicely without having to create a wrapper class using jersey-client / jaxb?

Comment: Did you try this? What was the result?

Comment: Yes, creating a `WidgetResponse` works. I updated the question to include the jaxb annotations that are used to make it work. However, I'd like a solution that doesn't require creating a container to hold the results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following two references led me to a solution ...

- [getEntity with GenericType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10587378/getentity-with-generictype)
- [Jersey REST Client](http://persistentdesigns.com/wp/2009/10/jersey-rest-client/)

Without a wrapper class the collection can be retrieved with the `@XmlRootElement` jaxb annotation applied to the model ...

```java
@XmlRootElement
public class Widget {
    ...
}
```

And then modifying the client call to use the `GenericType` class. To retrieve an array you can call ...

```java
Widget[] widgets = ClientBuilder.newClient()
    .target("http://host/api")
    .path("resource")
    .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    .get(new GenericType<Widget[]>(){});
```

Or similarly to retrieve a list you can call ...

```
List<Widget> widgets = ClientBuilder.newClient()
    .target("http://host/api")
    .path("resource")
    .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    .get(new GenericType<List<Widget>>(){});
```

Answer (score 0):

From JAXB point:

You can create XMLStreamReader and just skip first tag while unmarshalling.

```
 XMLInputFactory xmlInputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
 XMLStreamReader xmlStreamReader = xmlInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(new FileInputStream("widgets.xml"));
 xmlStreamReader.nextTag(); // <widgets>
 xmlStreamReader.nextTag(); // first <widget>
```